# Clearing drawn objects in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, erase

I have used this code to draw a set of ellipses in C# but I do not know how to erase them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I use to draw:

```
private void drawEllipseAnimation(double x, double y)
    {

        Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
        e.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
        e.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        e.Height = 10;
        e.Width = 10;
        e.Opacity = 1;
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(e);
        Canvas.SetLeft(e, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(e, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MainCanvas.Children.`[`Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.clear.aspx)?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just started using c#, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @miltonjbradley: Glad to help, but seriously, if you use an `Add` method why not look at the [other methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection_methods.aspx) first to see if there is anything useful?